# Extend Mysql table for same id

Tags: mysql

My table structure is:

`id | type | attribute | customer_id | value`

`1 |   2  |     1     |      1      | some`
`2 |   2  |     2     |      1      | this`
`3 |   2  |     3     |      1      | that`
`4 |   2  |     1     |      2      | cool`
`5 |   2  |     2     |      2      | just`

etc

I want to add **value**='mine' as **attribute** 4 to each **customer_id**.

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SET type='2', attribute='4, value='mine'
```

The question is how to bind it on customer_id and only once per customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO myTable(type, attribute, customer_id, value)
SELECT  2 type,
        4 attribute,
        s.customer_id,
        'mine' `value`
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM myTable) s
```

Comment: Thank you for promt answer.